# Oxyplot : how to programmatically get the scale of a linearAxis and use it in another linearAxis

Tags: c#, wpf, latitude-longitude, oxyplot

First question here, I hope I'm doing it right :-)

I'm currently trying to use Oxyplot. To be precise, I'd like to draw a heatmap, using a dataset of points (in the "lat, long, altitude" format). I already built the dataset without problem, the plot works fine, however the scale is wrong : as you probably know, on such a map, the scale on the longitude axis depends on the latitude ( as explained here : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110730/mercator-scale-factor-is-changed-along-the-meridians-as-a-function-of-latitude). How could I lock the scale of the longitude axis to (scale on the latitude axis * factor as seen in the stackexchange discussion) ? Knowing that the maps I have to draw represent a few dozen square kilometers at most, so the longitude scale can be considered constant on the map.

I wanted to know how I could set the scale of a linearAxis so that it is a multiple of that of another linearAxis. I tried to use the "Minimum" and "Maximum" properties of my linearAxis, but I struggle to adapt it to my situation. Am I on the right track ?

Thank you very much, and sorry if my English isn't good, non-native speaker writting.

Comment: You said that "on such a map, the scale on the longitude axis depends on the latitude" but the link clearly says "The Mercator scale depends only on the latitude.". As I understand the link, you only have to multiply the latitude by a factor. Do you know that factor?

Comment: Yes, you only need to multiply the latitude scale by a factor (at least that's how I understand it). The factor is known, it is sqrt(1 - e^2 sin^2(f)) * sec(f) at latitude f.

Comment: The problem is I cannot directly multiply my longitudes in the data to account for this factor, because I would like the axis labels on the graph to remain correct.